# Does the CPU or motherboard throttle?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, throttling

Can a CPU throttle itself, or is it the motherboard that does it?
By throttle, I mean when the CPU underclocks and undervolts itself due to high temperatures.

Comment: I'm unaware of any system which addjusts CPU frequency by the MB. CPU clock adjustment takes place either by software (example: AMD Cool 'n Quiet) or by the CPU itself (which can be disabled/enabled by software) (example: AMD Turbo Core). I would avoid the terms _underclock_ and _undervolt_ in this context because they're misleading. Turbo Core is simply frequency scaling and it may include frequencies lower and higher than the nominal one.

Comment: So it's the software in the BIOS then?

Comment: No BIOS involved in freq scaling except for enabling/disabling the general mechanism and/or overclocking. Windows: CPU driver. Linux: Frequency scaling governor. Essentially the same. All CPU cores usually run at maximum or nominal speed in early boot phase.

Comment: Thats odd... when I run the same OS on the same SSD on 2 different motherboards and processors, one gets underclocked frequently whereas the other doesn't...

Comment: And what is so odd about that?

Comment: [Here’s some documentation](http://www.intel.de/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/cpu-monitoring-dts-peci-paper.pdf) on this from Intel.

Comment: @ClassStacker The FX-8120 runs at 3.1ghz, and once it reaches 50c it underclocks to 1.4ghz. The FX-8320 at 4.0ghz doesn't underclock, and just shuts down at 90c. Same OS... why would it do something different to 2 very similar CPUs?

Comment: @Matthew The FX-8120 is a Bulldozer/Zambezi processor, while the FX-8320 is a Piledriver/Vishera processor. [I analysed the frequency scaling and thermal management details of a Richland processor](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148918/79761), which is the successor of Trinity (Piledriver + GPU). I found significant differences at detail level (not much public information about it). => Assuming FX-8120 and FX-8320 to be "similar" in this regard may not be helpful. -- The 50 deg C point is suspicious, though. But there's too much information missing to assess the root cause of what you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU can throttle itself, using configuration set by the EFI/BIOS config. The operating system can also communicate power management instructions to the CPU. The motherboard does not have such logic.

Comment: Whether the motherboard is involved depends on where the voltage regulators are and which component controls them.